# Android move end of line coordinate to face point but retain length

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, surfaceview

I have a line positioned at

```
Point lineStart = (screenWidth, screenHeight/2);
```

I want to retain its length as a fixed number, i.e.

```
int lineLength = 100
```

When the user taps any part of the screen, I hope to parse (x,y) values to

```
Point lineEnd;
```

How can I determine the coordinates to parse given a Touch Point whilst retaining the line's length? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can determine the coordinates by angle.

At first, get angle by arctan(line with lineStart and touchPoint)

And then, calculate lineEnd by angle above

```
Point getLineEnd(Point lineStart, Point touchPoint, int length) {
    double rad = Math.atan((touchPoint.y - lineStart.y) / (touchPoint.x - lineStart.x));
    Point lineEnd = new Point(lineStart);
    lineEnd.offset(length * Math.cos(rad), length * Math.sin(rad));
    return lineEnd;
}
```